# Firefox & Thunderbird 2020 how to restore menu in the system default style: in menu bar or in window's title bar? (Unity)

Tags: unity, firefox, 20.04, thunderbird, menu

With recent updates of Firefox (78) and Thunderbird (68.8) all menus have vanished from the system default place for menus. The menus should show in the menu bar (top of the screen) or in the window's title bar, according to the users system settings.

But now there are only 2 ways to access the menu: The menu button on the right side of the window, which is a hassle to go through with many sub menus, and to display the menu permanently inside the Thunderbird window, which is ugly and a waste of space.

Making the menu show by pressing the Alt key does not work any more too.

How can I get back the menus in practical and elegant "Unity-style"?

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer for Thunderbird 60, but it worked for me in 68. This may not provide all the flexibility you're after, but it will at least put the menu inside the title bar, which frees up some space.

> To disable the title bar at Thunderbird 60, you need to go to system
> menu Edit -> Preferences and choose Advanced tab. Then click at Config
> Editor at page left bottom corner, open it and look for
> mail.tabs.drawInTitlebar. Double clik on it and your bird should be
> titleless.